# ubuntu18.04 cannot detect second monitor via HDMI

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

output from `xrandr`

`Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+  40.00

DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

no HDMI entry

kernel version : 5.3.13-050313-generic

GPU:Quadro RTX 3000

NVIDIA Driver Version: 440.36

lightdm used

output from `lspci`

`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 0d)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a37c (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a368 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a369 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device a363 (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a353 (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33a (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33c (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a335 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f36 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f9 (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ada (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1adb (rev a1)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
06:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] (rev 06)
6f:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1527
70:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)`

and output from `xrandr --verbose`

`Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x21d
    Timestamp:  14953
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:

    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x21e
    Timestamp:  14953
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:

    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x21f
    Timestamp:  14953
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:

    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x221) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
    Identifier: 0x220
    Timestamp:  14953
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:

    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    Backlight: 55 
        range: (0, 100)
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000dae5e1700000000
        301c01049526157803a155a556519d28
        0b505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101b43b804a713834403020
        35007dd61000001acd27804a71383440
        302035007dd61000001a000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000002
        000c33ff0f3c96161d4896000000008d
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: Panel 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
  1920x1080 (0x221) 152.840MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2250 skew    0 clock  67.93KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1132           clock  60.01Hz
  1920x1080 (0x222) 101.890MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2250 skew    0 clock  45.28KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1132           clock  40.00Hz
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x223
    Timestamp:  14953
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:

    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1`

Answer (score 0):

solved. suspend for a minute and then wake it. i think it is a dp port matter